# Upper bound on truncation error of a fourier series approximation of a pdf?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Given a probability density function, $f\left(x\right)$, of a continuous random variable, $X$, and given an $N$-th order fourier series approximation:

$$f_N\left(x\right)=\sum_{n=-N}^{N}c_n e^{inx}$$

Is there an upper bound for the truncation error, for an arbitrary $f\left(x\right)$? (given only the assumptions $f\left(x\right) \ge 0$ and $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f\left(x\right)\text{d}x=1$)

Comment: I THINK you can write down the $L_2$ error, use the triangle inequality on that integral, and manipulate the terms to give you a bound, but I don't recall the details.

Comment: Or invoke parseval's theorem in that integral.  An IEEE paper from 1972 seems to have the details, "Bounds on the truncation error of periodic signals"

Comment: Did you mean $\int_{\mathbb{R}}$? Then we can choose $f$ to have support away from $[-\pi,\pi)$... Please explain more.

Comment: @AD.: If it helps, I'm interested in a pdf that is periodic, so pretend its on the unit circle and $\int_{0}^{2\pi}f\left(x\right)\text{d}x=1$

Comment: @okj Okay, then note that $\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)\,dx=1$ means $c_0=2\pi$. Also, what kind of an estimate would you expect? That is, for what norm $\|\cdot\|_\sigma$ should we estimate $$\|f-f_N\|_\sigma ?$$